# How to read files/images with CUDA in Google Colab?

Tags: cuda, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I'm learning CUDA and as I don't currently own a GPU I'm using Colab.
The idea of doing some image processing crossed my mind but I haven't found a way to load images to my program.

I know with python is possible to access your google drive but I'm using CUDA C++. Anybody got any suggestions, please?

Comment: CUDA has no such facilities. If you want to use google drive in C++,  you will need to find a C++ implementation of their APIs, if such a thing exists and is still supported (I fear it is not)

Comment: You may implement your own access methods using the http API here: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference

Comment: @talonmies Thanks for the heads up. I was hoping there was an easier way, like python. Thanks to both of you, I may explore the API option that Curtis says

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code to mount a folder from your Google Drive.
Then use it as you usually access files from C.

```html
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

%cd "/content/drive/My Drive/Your Folder"
!pwd
```

Comment: Thanks! It looks that actually works. I will try to do my thing